# Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Написал простенькую программу для запуска на удаленном сервере, но возникла банальная и глупая проблема. Запускаю с консоли:

```
username:my_parser user$ java errorParser.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class errorParser.jar
```

Класс `Main` соержит метод `main`.
Собирал из IDEA, на скриншоте параметризировал сборку через artifacts, далее Build > Build Artifacts

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? (mac os)

Comment: а у вас точно есть метод `public static void main(String[] argv)` _ровно_ в 1 классе.

Comment: @pavel все верно - в классе Main один единственный метод public static void main(String[] args) в одном экземпляре

Comment: `java -jar errorParser.jar` пробовали?

Comment: @Roman да пробовал, проблема та же - Could not find or load main class Main

Comment: Разархивируйте этот jar и покажите содержимое MANIFEST.MF и структуру папок/файлов внутри jar.

Comment: @Roman вы правы - архив jar содержит только MANIFEST.MF. Судя по всему я не правильно настроил сборку

Comment: @Roman я изменил конфигурацию - теперь содержимое jar файла похоже на корректное, но возникает все та же проблема:username:myfolder user$ java sms.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class sms.jar
username:myfolder user$ java -jar sms.jar 
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile sms.jar

Comment: Не знаю что я сделал не так, от проблемы избавился просто сконфигурировав pom.xml и собирал через консоль maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не понял что я сделал не так в настройке сборки артефактов в среде разработки. Но вместо этого решил использоваться стандартный сценарий - сконфигурировать `pom.xml` и собирать через консоль.
Сам `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>sms</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>

        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>

    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourse>1.7</sourse>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```